# Django admin. How to redirect the link on the model class to open the first object?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-urls

I have model in django it is 'Slogan' model. I restricted it to only 1 object from admin:

```
def has_add_permission(self, request):
    if len(Slogan.objects.all()) == 1:
        return False
    return True
```

My view in home page will create the first object on page load if there is no object slogan in the database.

What I want to do is when I open admin and click on the left side where Slogan is to open the first object of that class directly instead of seeing a list with objects on the right and select it from there.

I tried get_url() method from admin but this seems to be for the specific objects.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to redirect on the first object view/change form instead of changelist view of modeladmin then override `changelist_view()` method and handle on condition `first object exists or not`.

```
from django.shortcuts import reverse, redirect

class YourAdminClass(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        first_obj = self.model.objects.first()
        if first_obj is not None:
            return redirect(reverse('admin:<app_label>_<model_name>_change', args=(first_obj.pk,)))
        return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context)
```